# adding custom view and custom download buttons and manipulate in a folder in document library in SP 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

[image: image-generated-fromppt-slide-in-folder]

Here there exists a folder in a doc.lib, end users will be uploading the powerpoint slides for the persona. But instead of using the OOTB functionality, they want to create a separate UI on top of the default list view with view and download images

[ that may act as  buttons ] on click of the those the following should happen:

1) View image button :  when click on view the slide has to be populates as an IMAGE and enlarged manner

2)Download image button :on click of download the ppt slide has to be download to the end user's desl.

Is this possible  in SP 2013  without using server object model? how to create a  these two image buttons inside the folder as a column/ separate UI ? [ may be a impossible reqmnt??]

Comment: try using Client side rendering http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620110/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Views

Comment: let me know if it works

Comment: But, how to create & add those images as part of doc.lib o folder? If I click how to trigger an event that reads the contents of the slides and populate as. Image! Is this possible in SP??